# Proving $f(x)=2x+|x|$ is not differentiable at (0,0)

Tags: limits, derivatives

Prove $f(x)=2x+|x|$ is not differentiable at (0,0)

I know that the limit as x tends towards 0 from positive and negative of the derivative must be equal for it to be differentiable.

The mark scheme says:

[image]

I'm not sure how they get h/h for h tending to 0 from negative, but 3h/h is from just substituting in h into the function... Can someone explain how these numbers arise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if $x$ is a positive quantity, then $f(x)=2x+x=3x$ and if it is negative, $f(x)=2x-x=x$. Hope it helps ;)